# set selected item of listview according to a value

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, selected

C# winforms. 
I have a listview, and for each item clicked I show its properties in labels and textboxes.
They are not binded in any way, I do manually. 
So I change values in textboxes (via next and previous record buttons) and the listview.selected doesn't change.

I've done this my way, but I think maybe there's some optimization or even a single method to do this. I'm seeking something like selected=itemwithkey(idTextBox)

```
for (int i = 0; i < lstvClientes.Items.Count; i++) {
   if (lstvClientes.Items[i].SubItems[0].Text == idTextBox.Text) {
      lstvClientes.Items[i].Selected = true; break;
   }
}
```

Suggestions?
thank you community.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [ListView.FindItemWithText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.finditemwithtext.aspx)  method:

```
var item = lstvClientes.FindItemWithText(idTextBox.Text);
if (item != null)
    item.Selected = true;
```

Comment: Wouldn't this also have the possiblity of null reference exception?

Comment: @JeradRose nope, in previous solution method `Find` returned empty array instead of null, so `ToList()` created empty list

Comment: I'm pretty sure the version I commented on (not showing in history) had something like .Find().First().Selected(). But your current solution definitely resolves that.

Comment: @JeradRose before this was version with find.. `lstvClientes.Items.Find(idTextBox.Text, false).ToList().ForEach(i => i.Selected = true)`. But `Find` uses names of items, which are empty by default.

Comment: yep, working fine. method updated :D. 
+1 for remembering about the var thing.

Comment: @CristobalDeIncógnitoFlipo you even can accept this as solution :)